# X-Box Image Appears in Google Chrome on Windows OS especially in mobile view (NOT OSX)

Tags: windows, reactjs, google-chrome, web, mobile

on my Google Pixel phone there are strange characters instead of spaces.

[Image Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rB2M.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just copy your HTML code into this tool and clean it: http://www.nousphere.net/cleanspecial.php

It will show you the special characters after the conversion, just remove it from the text you pasted it and then copy it back into the HTML code. You will realize that you have to press the backspace button 2x.